# Shortcode to display Custom Post Type with specific categories and tags

Tags: custom-post-type, shortcode

I currently have the following shortcode, which works really well for displaying a custom post type in multiple categories. Is there a way to create a shortcode that searches by categories and tags?

Currently the shortcode looks like [Resources category="books, videos"] and displays all posts with both of those two categories.

What I'm looking for is maybe a shortcode that reads [Resources category="videos" tags="ministry, devotions"] which would result in only displaying posts in the category videos, which also have tags - ministry and devotions.

```
add_shortcode( 'Resources', 'resources' );

function resources( $atts, $shrt_content = null ) {

$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'category' => ''
), $atts, '');

$categories  = ! empty( $atts['category'] ) ? explode( ',' , $atts['category'] ) : '';

$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'resource',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'title',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'tax_query'         => array( array(
                                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                'field'     => 'slug',
                                'operator'  => 'AND',
                                'terms'     => $categories
                            ) )
    );

$post_query = new WP_Query( $args );

ob_start();

if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) { ?>   

<?php while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php if(get_field('short_description')) { echo ' - ' . get_field('short_description') . ''; } ?></p>   
        
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php 
}
$retVal = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $retVal; 
}
```